# C# GC.Collect() and Memory

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I am receiving a very large list as a method argument and would like to remove it from memory after it is used.  Normally I would let the GC do its thing, but I need to be very careful of memory usage in this app.

Will this code accomplish my goal?  I've read a lot of differing opinions and am confused.

```
public void Save(IList<Employee> employees)
    {
        // I've mapped the passed-in list
        var data = Mapper<Employee, EmployeeDTO>.MapList(employees);

        // ?????????????
        employees = null;
        GC.Collect();

        // Continues to process very long running methods....
        // I don't want this large list to stay in memory

   }
```

Maybe I should use another technique that I'm not aware of?

Comment: If the list is not used anymore the GC will automatically collect it _when available memory is an issue_.  Unless you have a measurable problem don't try and outsmart the GC.

Comment: If you have to be _very careful_ with memory in your application then don't pass very large lists as arguments. Even if the GC is doing its job, if you have multiple threads processing this data, the very large list may get allocated several times.

Comment: The reference is passed by value, so by definition the call is still rooting the list, which means that it is not eligible for GC.

Comment: @DStanley...This is a 64 bit .exe running on a Windows 2008 server so I'm limited to 8gb ram (so I'm told).  I am getting close to this and want to avoid a OOM exception.

Comment: The best way to make sure that something is removed from memory is simply to make sure that all references to it are erased when you're finished using it.  Period.  The GC will run on its own when it needs to and will free anything that doesn't have a reference to it.  As has been said, don't try to outsmart the GC.

Comment: @xxbbcc, passing a list will not get allocated multiple lines. You would need to explicitly copy it to do that. Only the reference to the list is passed (or if you specify byref, then the reference to the reference is passed).

Comment: @BigDaddy The GC will free up memory _if it can_ to avoid OOM exceptions - if something is holding a reference to it (and there is code that will/could use it) then GC will not collect it even if you call `.Collect()`

Comment: Where does the big list come from originally? What exactly are you doing with it? If you're making a modification to a bunch of employees can you do it with a mass update statement instead of loading/saving?

Comment: "64bit" and "so limited to 8GB" is very strange combination. You really need to work hard to get OOM in x64...

Comment: "remove it from memory" or "allow it to be used again"?  It's likely that the data that was in the list will still be in memory after a forced GC and will remain there until re-used/initialized by something else (even if the GC could collect the list where you call Collect).

Comment: @SamuelNeff...This is passed from another assembly that I don't have control over.  I map its items to DTOs and then save them to the DB

Comment: Sometimes it is beneficial to force a collection deterministically, at a certain time, than it is to have it occur indeterministically and risk the app look unresponsive randomly...

Comment: @PeterRitchie...I don't understand your last comment.  Are you saying that sometimes it's okay to use GC.Collect?  Maybe sometimes  we devs know better that the GC?

Comment: Judging by the quality of the responders and their responses, I don't understand how anyone could justify downvoting this question.

Comment: @SamuelNeff I didn't say "passing the list" allocates it multiple time. I said calling this function on multiple threads (with supposedly unique inputs) will allocate a lot of memory if the assumption is that the input list is very large. If memory is a concern then holding a large list in memory is not the best approach.

Comment: @xxbbcc, thanks for the clarification. That's not how I interpreted your earlier comment.

Comment: @SamuelNeff Yeah, I re-read it and I'm not sure you could've interpreted otherwise. I thought I was clearer when I wrote it up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the list is not used anymore the GC will automatically collect it *when available memory is an issue*.

However, if the *caller* uses the list after passing it to your function then the GC *won't* collect it even if you set it to null (all you have is a reference to the list - you can't do anything about other objects that hold references as wel).

Unless you have a measurable problem don't try and outsmart the GC.

Comment: I am close to having a measurable problem.  Since I'm running the 64 bit app on a Win 2008 server I'm limited to 8gb memory and I'm rapidly approaching this threshold.  I've never considered manually   manipulating the GC, but I ran out of ideas.

Comment: Depending which Windows Server 2008 version you are running, you probably are not physically limited to 8GB of memory. You may only have 8GB installed, but all versions of Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2 (with the exception of Server 2008 R2 Foundation) allow much more than 8GB of physical memory when running x64. See [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx#physical_memory_limits_windows_server_2008_r2) from Microsoft.

Comment: @BigDaddy Then I would look at processing in chunks (upstream of `Save`) and/or making sure that you aren't holding on to the list somewhere else. if the caller just passes the list in and doesn't do anything else with it then it should be collected when there is memory pressure.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a direct answer to the question but some ideas how to handle the low-memory situations the poster (@Big Daddy) referred to.

If you're running into low memory situations on an x64 platform with 8 GB of memory, you should determine if your application is responsible for it. If it is, then run a memory profiler (CLR Profiler or something else or even get a full user dump and run WinDbg on it) to see what allocates the memory. It's possible that you have some objects that are not used anymore but are still referenced somewhere - this is not a true memory leak but it's memory that's not freed up in your application - most decent profilers will identify big objects (or objects with a lot of instances) along with their types.

I find it hard to believe that the list passed to this `Save` function would stress a server with 8 GB of memory but we don't know how much free memory is available to the process and what kind of a process it is (IIS, desktop, etc.)

If `Save` is called on several threads with huge inputs, it can potentially lead to memory stress but even then, it's not very likely and I'd check various counters and profile data to see when and why memory stress happens.